# TabControl blinks on mouse hover after resizing window

Tags: winforms, tabcontrol

I have a TabControl that is placed in a window that has an image background.  I had an issue in the past that caused the tab headers to blink on mouse hover.  Using the solution found here: [TabControl blinks if image is background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3111841/tabcontrol-blinks-if-image-is-background) I was able to fix it.  However whenever the window is resized the issue resurfaces.  Is there a way to make sure this 'CreateParams' property is called again when the window is resized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you are running out of magic here.  You took the bluepill to solve your problem, the real issue is that the background image is too expensive to draw.

Next workaround is to not have the panel resize itself when the user resizes the form.  Reset the Anchor and/or Dock properties, override the form's OnResizeEnd() method to change the size of the panel.  It now snaps into place as soon as the user stops dragging, there's only one paint instead of many.

Comment: I tried removing the dock setting on the ResizeBegin() and setting it it on the ResizeEnd() event.  However I still get the blinking when I hover over any of the tab headers.

Comment: Wasn't that already covered by your previous question?  What did you change?

Comment: Your solution from the previous question solves the issue until the window is resized after loading in which it occurs again for the remaining life of the application.

Comment: No repro.  Something else weird about this: why do you use a BackgroundImage *and* dock the tab control?  You won't be able to see the image but for a small strip to the top-right of the control.  Why not just draw the little bit that's visible in the form's OnPaintBackground method?

Answer (score -1):

There is another fix around. It might introduce some problems with XP, but it sure worked instantly for me.

[TabControl blinks if image is background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3111841/tabcontrol-blinks-if-image-is-background)